# Update existing header field in asterisk

Tags: header, addition, asterisk

I am new to and working on asterisk. I have a question.
How to extend a string to an existing header field in asterisk?
For example, after calling:

```
add_header(req, "User_Note", "swim fast");
```

User_Note has value "swim fast". I want to add "run quickly" to the value of "User_Note". So "User_Note" will be "swim fast, run quickly".

Comment: I found a guide here: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Page Perhaps, I need to modify conf file like this: exten => s,3,SIPAddHeader(Supported: "swim fast");

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to Asterisk dialplan code, you can't remove a SIP header that comes in with the call. You can add another instance of the same header using [`SIPAddHeader()`](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_SIPAddHeader), and change the code on the far end to interpret multiple values correctly.

The example you have up there is not Asterisk dialplan though.

Comment: Thank you. For my case, I need to add information to "Supported" field so I updated add_supported() function's source code directly.